# Bittrex API Returns "result" [object Object]

Tags: api, angular6

using Angular 6 I can't figure out how to display the "result" array from Bittrex API request https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-ltc

I can get the API, no problem and display the objects, but the result array comes out like [object Object]

success true
message
result  [object Object]

Here is the HTML code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let price of objectKeys(prices)">
  <td>{{ price }}</td>
  <td>{{ prices[price] }}</td>
</tr>
```

I just want to know the correct HTML code to display any one of the parameters within the result array. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**edit: added full code**

data.service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {


  result: any;

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   getPrice() {
    return this.http.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-ltc')

  }

}
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  objectKeys = Object.keys;
  prices: any;


  constructor(private data: DataService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getPrice()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.prices = res;

      });


  }
}
```

component.html

```
<h2>Bittrex Results</h2>
<div *ngIf="prices">
  <table id="pricetable">
    <tr>
      <th>Bittrex Close</th>
      <th>Bittrex Volume</th>
      <th>Test</th>

    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let price of objectKeys(prices)">
      <td>{{ price }}</td>
      <td>{{ prices[price] }}</td>
      <td>{{ prices[price] }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpYw6.png)

Comment: Can you add the code you use the show the `[object Object]` you mentioned? You could try checking it out with a `console.log`.

Comment: @Arkanoid added console log image at the bottom. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the JSON you get, the object contains a property named `result` which is the array containing prices.

So you have to use this property, like this:

```
this.data.getPrice()
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.prices = res.result;
  });
```